# Importing python module in c# using pythonnet

Tags: python.net

I noticed there are two different ways to import a python module in pythonnet in c#:

```
var testModule = PythonEngine.ImportModule("testModule");
```

and

```
using (Py.GIL())
{
    var testModule = Py.Import("testModule");
{
```

What are the reasons for using one over the other?

Comment: The latter is simpler limited new API

Comment: I have a related question to this. Where should these python files be present? In the site-packages folder or in a separate python project in the same solution?